How can I retrieve validation domain for ACM certificate?
I am trying to setup a CDK that deploys a cloudfront site to a different account than where the HostedZone is.
I have gotten it to work where it creates the ACM certificate and then the cloud formation deployment waits for me to validate ownership of the domain. I can log into the console in the primary account, add the validation CNAME record, and the cloud formation deployment then continues successfully. It deploys the site to cloudfront and attaches the ACM certificate, and it updates the DNS entries in the hosted zone with an A record to route DNS requests to the cloudfront site.
I am trying to remove that manual step in the middle.
I am using this construct: https://constructs.dev/packages/cdk-cross-account-route53/v/1.0.1?lang=typescript
Which should allow the delegated account to also create a CNAME record, however I can't figure out how to get the auto-generated validation record/value that the ACM Certificate wants me to use to prove ownership. How can I accomplish this?
Existing code snippets.
DNS stack:
export class DnsStack extends cdk.Stack {
  constructor(scope: Construct, id: string, props: DnsStackProps) {
    super(scope, id, props);

    const zone = route53.PublicHostedZone.fromHostedZoneId(
      this,
      "delegatedDnsZone",
      "zoneId",
    );

    new CrossAccountRoute53Role(this, "WebRoute53Role", {
      roleName: props.configurationValues.dnsAssumeRole,
      assumedBy: new iam.AccountPrincipal(props.configurationValues.webAccount),
      zone: zone,
      records: [
        {
          domainNames: [
            props.configurationValues.uiCustomDomain,
            "*." + props.configurationValues.uiCustomDomain,
          ],
        },
      ],
    });
  }
}

UI stack:
this.acmCertificate = new acm.Certificate(this, "Certificate", {
  domainName: props.configurationValues.uiCustomDomain,
  certificateName: "AWS Test Cert",
  validation: acm.CertificateValidation.fromDns(),
});

this.cloudFrontDistribution = new cloudfront.Distribution(
  this,
  "CfDistribution",
  {
    webAclId: "acl",
    defaultBehavior: {
      origin: new origins.S3Origin(this.deploymentBucket),
    },
    certificate: this.acmCertificate,
    errorResponses: [
      {
        httpStatus: 403,
        responseHttpStatus: 200,
        ttl: cdk.Duration.seconds(10),
        responsePagePath: "/index.html",
      },
      {
        httpStatus: 404,
        responseHttpStatus: 200,
        ttl: cdk.Duration.seconds(10),
        responsePagePath: "/index.html",
      },
    ],
    domainNames: [props.configurationValues.uiCustomDomain],
  },
);

new CrossAccountRoute53RecordSet(this, "ARecord", {
  delegationRoleName: props.configurationValues.dnsAssumeRole,
  delegationRoleAccount: props.configurationValues.dnsAccount, // The account that contains the zone and role
  hostedZoneId: props.configurationValues.hostedZoneId,
  resourceRecordSets: [
    {
      Name: props.configurationValues.uiCustomDomain,
      Type: "A",
      AliasTarget: {
        DNSName: this.cloudFrontDistribution.distributionDomainName,
        HostedZoneId: "Z2FDTNDATAQYW2", // This is always the Hosted Zone Id for Cloudfront
        EvaluateTargetHealth: false,
      },
    },
  ],
});


You need to include the code for your CrossAccountRoute53Role and CrossAccountRoute53RecordSet constructs. AWS CDK provides PublicHostedZone.grantDelegation method to grant your role the needed access, and the CrossAccountZoneDelegationRecord to create the delegation record.

The code for CrossAccountRoute53Role and CrossAccountRoute53RecordSet is in the package I'm using,  https://constructs.dev/packages/cdk-cross-account-route53/v/1.0.1?lang=typescript  From what I read, the PublicHostedZone.grantDelegation allows a sub-zone to create delegation records, but I don't have that. My hostedZone is company.com and I'm trying to create a cert for app.company.com in another account. There is no sub-zone.
